# How add custom style max width 1024 Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, less

I have:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    padding: 50 px;
}
```

Css looks: `@media (min-width: 768px) { padding 50px }`

Need make: `@media (max-width: 1024px) { padding 10px }`
I try change style in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Theme/web/css/sourse/_module.less`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `lib/web/css/source/lib/_responsive.less`.
Define your screen variable in `_theme.less` in your theme.
And copy this file into your theme dir in:
`web/css/source/lib/_responsive.less`.
Add your line in that file properly. The order matters.

I see now that you've asked for `@screen_l: 1024px;` variable which is already defined in `lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_responsive.less`.

Try to put after:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: @screen__m) {
    .media-width('max', (@screen__m + 1));
}
```

This:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: @screen__l) {
    .media-width('max', (@screen__l));
    // or @screen_l + 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I need insert this code to _responsive.less or to file (where I make changes) _module.less?

Comment: In _responsive.less. You want to override the original _responsive.less into your theme folder where you copy this file and than modify it. And in your _module.less use your `.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__l) {`

Answer (score 0):

for those that want a super hacky way you can just add to the html head (content > configuration > edit default store view)

```
body{max-width 1024px;}
```

Answer (score -3):

I want to Add min-width:249px and max-width:449px css in less in Magento 2.0.
How to do?

Comment: That's not an answer to this question it is rather a new question.